# How to make a ScrollView in android scrollable?

Tags: android

I have the following layout, probably with many many errors:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "0dp">

        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/new_cancel"
                android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                android:columnCount="10"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:useDefaultMargins="true">

                <TextView
                 // TextViews and EditText etc...
                 // ...

            </GridLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The main part (`GridLayout`) contains several input fields to input text, numbers etc. But when I click on such an input field the touch-keypad opens and overlaps part of my input fields! Although this `ViewGroup` is placed inside a `ScrollView`, I am not able to scroll it!

How to change the layout so I can scroll the stuff inside the `GridLayout`...?

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest` write

```
<activity
    android:name="<yourpackage>.MainActivity"
    ... 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

This will resize your activity when keyboard opens

Comment: Nope does not work. Maybe I have to clean the project?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `scrollView`and add this to the `onCreate` of your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

This will resize the `activity`'s on keyboard open

Comment: Why remove the `ScrollView`?